# radius of convergence of integral of power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence R. What is the radius of convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n x^{n+1}}{n+1}$?

How do I solve this without using power series integration?

Comment: Which characterizations of the radius of convergence of a series do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Given $R=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}\right|$

Also, let $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n-1} x^{n}}{n}=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n} x^{n}$$

where $b_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}$

$R_1=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}\times\frac{n+1}{a_{n}}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{n+1}{n}\right|\times \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}\right|$. You know where to go from here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $R=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$?

Comment: @Olga, $\frac1R=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks!

Comment: This does not solve the exercise since it may well happen that the ratios $\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$ have no limit (these could even be undefined for infinitely many $n$s...).

Comment: @Did, true. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: A better option would be to repair the solution...

Comment: @Did, actually, ratio $\left|{a_n\over a_{n+1}}\right|$ does have a limit according to the question (and equal to $R$)

Comment: Not at all, try $\sum\limits_nx^{2n}$.

Comment: @Did, In the question, it is given as $R$, the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

Comment: Yes I know (I can read), thus $R$ is not defined as the (possibly nonexistent) limit of the ratios. (Please grab your notes on entire series and check them for a *definition* of their radius of convergence...)

Comment: @Did, I am confused at the moment, please do post the right answer (or feel free to edit mine)!

Comment: Sorry but why is it impossible to check the definition in your notes? Ya know, just to stop being confused...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34640/discussion-between-jesse-p-francis-and-did).

Comment: Note that the ratio test is inconclusive if $R=1$.  Also, try the ratio test on the simple problem: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0\cdot x^n$$ You will find a $\frac00$ problem, even though the radius of convergence is without a doubt trivial.

Answer (score 0):

One nice characterisation of the radius of convergence $R$ of a power series $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$ is given by the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://www.example.com/):

$$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$$

Try applying this to your two sums.